# Converting array where elements have varying amounts of comma-separated data to a data.frame

Tags: r, performance

I have an lengthy array where each element has data separated by commas.  The first piece of data in each element is an identifier ID. The rest of the data consists of sets of two data points. We will call them X and Z. Here is an example.

My array looks like this:

```
ABC,1,1.5,2,2.4,3,3.1
DEF,1,1.7,2,0.9
GHI,3,8.2
JKL,1,1.5,2,2.4,3,3.13,8.2
```

I want it convert it into a data frame that look like this:

```
    ID X   Z
1  ABC 1 1.5
2  ABC 2 2.4
1  ABC 1 1.5
2  ABC 2 2.4
3  ABC 3 3.1
4  DEF 1 1.7
5  DEF 2 0.9
6  GHI 3 8.2
7  JKL 1 1.5
8  JKL 2 2.4
9  JKL 3 3.1
10 JKL 3 8.2
```

I wrote a loop (pasted below) that will do this for me, but it is very inefficient. My array is close to 1,000,000 elements long and the loop is taking forever. Any suggestions would be helpful. I'm still familiarizing myself with the apply functions but I'm not aware of how I could write one in this case.

In this code, the array with the raw data is called "lines".

```
#write a function to test if an itteration is even
is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0 

#create the dataframe, empty so I can add to it;
dfA <- data.frame()
itter <- 0

#start loop over lines of the array;
for (i in 1:length(lines)){
  #for (i in 1:10){
  itter <- itter + 1
  print(itter)
  line_data <- strsplit(lines[i], ",")
  #start loop over list containing data elements in each line
  for (j in 1:length(line_data[[1]])){

    filename = line_data[[1]][1]
    if (j>1){
      if (is.even(j)){
        X = as.numeric(line_data[[1]][j])
        Z = as.numeric(line_data[[1]][j+1])

        if (!exists("dfA")){
          dfA = data.frame("ID" = filename, "X" = X, "Z"=Z)
        }
        else{
          df_temp = data.frame("ID" = filename, "X" = X, "Z"=Z)
          dfA = rbind(dfA, df_temp)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: This is not an array. Why do you believe a data.frame would be an appropriate data structure for this data? Are missing values `NA`? Are they always missing in the corresponding column? Or should all values in one column and the string (repeated) in a second column?

Comment: Try `read.csv(text = "ABC,1,1.5,2,2.4,3,3.1\nDEF,1,1.7,2", fill = T, header = F, row.names = 1)`.

Comment: Sorry all, I hadn't completed the question when I accidentally hit submit. See completed question.

Comment: @rozkosz See updated text

Comment: @Roland See updated text of my question. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for the suggestion. I'm checking into it and I'll get back with you.

Comment: Don't grow an object in a loop. That's the slowest operation you can do in R.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for the tip. I guess I must have missed learning this. Do you know of any documentation/books/papers I could read that would help me retrain myself with how I approach coding in R so as to not think in terms of loops?

Comment: [The R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is a classic.

Comment: @Roland, thanks. Definitely will read. Abstract is great: "If you are using R and you think you’re in hell, this is a map for you."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest writing a function like the following:

```
tableMaker <- function(invec) {
  ## http://stackoverflow.com/q/30528592/1270695
  require(data.table)
  ## Split up the vector
  temp <- strsplit(invec, ",", TRUE)
  ## How long is each vector?
  a <- lengths(temp)
  ## Which vectors need adjustment?
  ind <- which(a %% 2 == 0)
  ## Adjust only those that need adjustment
  temp[ind] <- lapply(temp[ind], function(x) {
    c(x[1:(length(x)-1)], x[length(x)-2], x[length(x)])
  })
  ## Recalculate lengths
  a <- lengths(temp)
  ## Figure out where the IDs are
  a2 <- c(1, cumsum(a[-length(a)]) + 1)
  ## Unlist the data
  tempUL <- unlist(temp)
  ## Grab the IDs and repeat them to the necessary length
  ID <- rep(tempUL[a2], a/2)
  ## Make a 2 column matrix from the remaining values
  MAT <- matrix(tempUL[-a2], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
                dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Z")))
  ## Combine it into a data.table and run type.convert
  data.table(ID, MAT)[, lapply(.SD, type.convert)]
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
tableMaker(dat)
#      ID X    Z
#  1: ABC 1 1.50
#  2: ABC 2 2.40
#  3: ABC 3 3.10
#  4: DEF 1 1.70
#  5: DEF 2 0.90
#  6: GHI 3 8.20
#  7: JKL 1 1.50
#  8: JKL 2 2.40
#  9: JKL 3 3.13
# 10: JKL 3 8.20
```

On a dataset with 1,000,000 values, this runs in a few seconds:

```
dat2 <- rep(dat, 1000000/length(dat))

system.time(out <- tableMaker(dat2))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.284   0.000   3.053 
out
#           ID X    Z
#       1: ABC 1 1.50
#       2: ABC 2 2.40
#       3: ABC 3 3.10
#       4: DEF 1 1.70
#       5: DEF 2 0.90
# ---           
# 2499996: GHI 3 8.20
# 2499997: JKL 1 1.50
# 2499998: JKL 2 2.40
# 2499999: JKL 3 3.13
# 2500000: JKL 3 8.20
```

---

I haven't tested [@Roland's approach](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/d4134bcb2a6e288447eb#comment-1463413) on 1M values, but here is a comparison with 1000 values:

```
library(microbenchmark)
dat1000 <- rep(dat, 1000/length(dat))
microbenchmark(tableMaker(dat1000), roland(dat1000), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  tableMaker(dat1000)   2.346186   2.53734   2.647924   2.573726   2.730987   3.048823    10
#      roland(dat1000) 382.857587 391.46409 406.925600 402.442203 412.203468 452.420665    10
```

And here it is with 10k values:

```
dat10k <- rep(dat, 10000/length(dat))
microbenchmark(tableMaker(dat10k), roland(dat10k), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  tableMaker(dat10k)   19.24391   22.51366   24.57222   23.43996   27.11431   30.54927     5
#      roland(dat10k) 6286.45480 6324.42184 6497.16173 6325.32259 6355.39668 7194.21274     5
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You've got some really cool ideas in here!

Comment: @user1500158 Did you by any chance try it out with your actual data? How did the timing compare with a real-world case?

Comment: Trying to get it working on the actual data. lengths? what package is this in?

Comment: @user1500158, it is in the most recent version of R (recently added)

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully I understood the rules for creating the expected output correctly.

```
#import data
dat <- readLines(textConnection("ABC,1,1.5,2,2.4,3,3.1
DEF,1,1.7,2,0.9
GHI,3,8.2
JKL,1,1.5,2,2.4,3,3.13,8.2")) #use the file name instead of the text connection

#split lines
dat <- strsplit(dat, ",", fixed = TRUE)

#parse
res <- lapply(dat, function(x) {
  y <- type.convert(x[-1])
  test <- length(y) %% 2 #unequal count of numbers?
  z <- y[seq_len(length(y) - test)]
  mat <- matrix(z, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  if (test == 1L) mat <- rbind(mat, c(mat[nrow(mat), 1], tail(y, 1)))
  data.frame(ID = x[1], 
             X = mat[,1],
             Z = mat[,2])
})

#rbind result
do.call(rbind, res)
#    ID X    Z
#1  ABC 1 1.50
#2  ABC 2 2.40
#3  ABC 3 3.10
#4  DEF 1 1.70
#5  DEF 2 0.90
#6  GHI 3 8.20
#7  JKL 1 1.50
#8  JKL 2 2.40
#9  JKL 3 3.13
#10 JKL 3 8.20
```